# how to create matrix functions in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, trigonometry, equation

[I want to Implement the following trigonometric system of equations in MATLAB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ak1yu.png)

[image]
What script should i write solve for `x1,x2 and x4` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try build a system of equations in a function `f` and use `fsolve` to solve the system, i.e.,

```
function y = f(x)
 y = zeros(3,1);
 y(1) =  cos(x(1)-x(2)-x(3)) - 0.707;
 y(2) =  5*cos(x(1)) + 3*cos(x(1)-x(2)) - 3;
 y(3) =  5*sin(x(1)) + 3*sin(x(1)-x(2)) - 4;
end

[x, fval, info] = fsolve (@f, [0;0;0])
```

such that

```
x =

   1.5367
   1.8755
  -1.1244

fval =

  -0.000000014158
  -0.000000103868
  -0.000000551463

info =  1
```